# Why are multiple multiprocessing imap's blocking?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I want to do multiple transformations on some data. I figured I can use multiple `Pool.imap`'s because each of the transformations is just a simple map. And `Pool.imap` is lazy, so it only does computation when needed.

But strangely, it looks like multiple consecutive `Pool.imap`'s are blocking. And not lazy. Look at the following code as an example.

```py
import time
from multiprocessing import Pool

def slow(n):
    time.sleep(0.01)
    return n*n


for i in [10, 100, 1000]:
    with Pool() as p:
        numbers = range(i)
        iter1 = p.imap(slow, numbers)
        iter2 = p.imap(slow, iter1)

        start = time.perf_counter()
        next(iter2)
        print(i, time.perf_counter() - start)
        
# Prints
# 10 0.0327413540071575
# 100 0.27094774100987706
# 1000 2.6275791430089157
```

As you can see the time to the first element is increasing. I have 4 cores on my machine, so it roughly takes 2.5 seconds to process 1000 items with a 0.01 second delay. Hence, I think two consecutive `Pool.imap`'s are blocking. And that the first `Pool.imap` finishes the entire workload before the second one starts. That is not lazy.

I've did some additional research. It does not matter if I use a process pool or a thread pool. It happens with `Pool.imap` and `Pool.imap_unordered`. The blocking takes longer when I do a third `Pool.imap`. A single `Pool.imap` is not blocking. This [bug report](https://bugs.python.org/issue40110) seems related but different.

Comment: A workload of 0.01s is not very efficient for a process. Most CPU resources will go to the OS creating and cleaning up processes.

Comment: I know. It also happens with threads. Or when the sleep is longer.

Comment: I don't quite understand what *other* behaviour you expect. The point of ``Pool`` is that you have some workers processing your tasks – submitting ``iter1`` first means the pool tackles it first as well. The ``Pool`` doesn't know if, when, or in what order you expect the results, only in what order you submitted.

Comment: Because `imap` is supposed to be lazy. I.e. only doing work when needed. Or at least yield the done jobs before all others are finished. Using consecutive `imap`'s breaks this pattern.

Comment: imap is lazy in that you can get the first result before the last is ready. It still starts processing immediately - if processing were in lockstep with iteration, that would defeat the purpose of parallelising.

Comment: That is not lazy imho. Also, there is no need to be blocking. It could instead prefetch a certain number of items, reducing memory usage and lag. Anyway, the docs don't specify what is meant with "lazier" afaik.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR**  `imap` is not a real generator, meaning it does not generate items on-demand (lazy computation aka similar to coroutine), and pools initiate "jobs" in serial.

**longer answer:** Every type of submission to a `Pool` be it `imap`, `apply`, `apply_async` etc.. gets written to a queue of "jobs". This queue is read by a thread in the main process (`pool._handle_tasks`) in order to allow jobs to continue to be initiated while the main process goes off and does other things. This thread contains a very simple double for loop (with a lot of error handling) that basically iterates over each job, then over each task within each job. The inner loop blocks until a worker is available to `get` each task, meaning tasks (and jobs) are always started in serial in the exact order they were submitted. This does not mean they will finish in perfect serial, which is why `map`, and `imap` collect results, and re-order them back to their original order (handled by `pool._handle_resluts` thread) before passing back to the main thread.

**Rough pseudocode of what's going on:**

```py
#task_queue buffers task inputs first in - first out
pool.imap(foo, ("bar", "baz", "bat"), chunksize=1)
#put an iterator on the task queue which will yield "chunks" (a chunk is given to a single worker process to compute)
pool.imap(fun, ("one", "two", "three"), chunksize=1)
#put a second iterator to the task queue

#inside the pool._task_handler thread within the main proces
for task in task_queue: #[imap_1, imap_2]
#this is actually a while loop in reality that tries to get new tasks until the pool is close()'d
    for chunk in task:
        _worker_input_queue.put(chunk) # give the chunk to the next available worker
        # This blocks until a worker actually takes the chunk, meaning the loop won't
        # continue until all chunks are taken by workers.

def worker_function(_worker_input_queue, _worker_output_queue):
    while True:
        task = _worker_input_queue.get() #get the next chunk of tasks
        #if task == StopSignal: break
        result = task.func(task.args)
        _worker_output_queue.put(result) #results are collected, and re-ordered
                                         # by another thread in the main process
                                         # as they are completed.
```

Comment: Thanks! Could you elaborate a bit more on why this makes it blocking? Is it because the outer for loop only starts with the job of the second imap once the first one is finished?

Comment: @Pieter yes the outer loop only starts the second imap once all the tasks (iterations) of the first one have been submitted (though not necessarily finished). I'll write up a simplified pseudocode of what's going on...